# Learning Resources for Salesforce Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am starting out in Salesforce Marketing Cloud (SFMC). I am already a developer on the Core Salesforce platform and was wondering what is the best way to learn SFMC. I have access to a test environment and premier training videos btw. But what I found is some of the training videos are outdated.

And unfortunately, there is no trailhead for SFMC yet.

Any help videos/books/blogs to get started would be much appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Connect to Your Customers with Marketing Cloud](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/summer_16/summer_16_marketing) Trailhead unit is available as part of the Summer '16 Release module.

In addition, I'd recommend checking out:

1. [Marketing Cloud product documentation](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/)
2. [code.exacttarget.com](https://code.exacttarget.com/) for API, App development and AMPscript resources
3. [Marketing Cloud Technical Library](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/technical_library/) (you will find that some of this content has also been replicated on code.exacttarget.com)
4. [Marketing Cloud - How to Essentials videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLWzH8Vzi6rwbZbalGqrEEjXK-BYZ3jeRE) (these are all recent)

Comment: Thanks @Eliot Harper, any idea on what the two new trials would be on ?

Comment: @BobGali, I've checked my notes from CNX16, and it doesn't specifically mention two trails (I thought it did) however there is a Trailhead unit already available for Marketing Cloud. I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Is there a free playground account for SFMC to get hands dirty? We do have an SF Enterprise edition and can it help us anyway? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I have created a free tutorial series for marketing cloud.  Hope this helps

- Part 1: [Email Marketing Best Practices](https://sfdcfanboy.com/2018/12/02/marketing-cloud-email-specialist-certification-part-1-email-marketing-best-practices/)
- Part 2: [Email Content Creation](https://sfdcfanboy.com/2018/12/02/marketing-cloud-email-specialist-certification-part-2-content-creation/)
- Part 3: [Email Delivery](https://sfdcfanboy.com/2018/12/02/marketing-cloud-email-specialist-certification-part-3-email-delivery/)
- Part 4: [Email Message Design](https://sfdcfanboy.com/2018/12/02/marketing-cloud-email-specialist-certification-part-4-email-message-design/)
- Part 5: [Marketing Automation](https://sfdcfanboy.com/2018/12/02/marketing-cloud-email-specialist-certification-part-5-marketing-automation/)
- Part 6: [Data Management](https://sfdcfanboy.com/2018/12/02/marketing-cloud-email-specialist-certification-part-6-data-management/)
- Part 7: [Subscribers Management](https://sfdcfanboy.com/2018/12/02/marketing-cloud-email-specialist-certification-part-7-subscriber-management/)
- Part 8: [Data Segmentation](https://sfdcfanboy.com/2018/12/02/marketing-cloud-email-specialist-certification-part-8-data-segmentation/)
- Part 9: [Tracking & Reporting](https://sfdcfanboy.com/2018/12/02/marketing-cloud-email-specialist-certification-part-9-tracking-reporting/)
- Part 10: [FTP Guide](https://sfdcfanboy.com/2018/12/02/marketing-cloud-email-specialist-certification-part-10-ftp-guide/)

Answer (score 0):

Recently hopped on Trailhead to see if were any Trailmix and found a few here - https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/search?keywords=marketing%20cloud

But out of those, the detailed and helpful Trailmixes that I think are below 2 links:

- https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/users/00550000007w1htAAA/trailmixes/marketing-cloud

This has mix bag of SFMC+Pardot and the below has purely Marketing cloud learnings saving ~ 5 hours of trails.

- https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/users/00550000006J6XDAA0/trailmixes/marketing-cloud

Hope that helps.